# Jenkins with SSH key

Tags: shell, ssh, jenkins

I am trying to run a script on a remote server..I have created ssh key and tested running it from my remote server to another remote server where my script is located, after trying to run it I have succeeded. I have jenkins installed on my server which there I tried the same command in order to run the script on the remote server... it failed.

this is what I tried in my jenkins job:

```
ssh -i /path/to/my/private/key user@host_name /path/to/my/script/clean_cache_ruby.sh
```

I am getting in Jenkins the following error: Host key verification failed.

how can i make it run from Jenkins as it run perfectly from my server when I try the same command on the server terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ssh option StrictHostKeyChecking option.

`ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path/to/my/private/key user@host_name /path/to/my/script/clean_cache_ruby.sh`

Or another option is to manually add the finger print to /var/lib/jenkins/.ssh/known_hosts

Comment: unfortunately it did not work. I added the server to known_hosts and tried as well the command u just showed me... nothing happened.

This is the error message I got:
  Host key verification failed.

Comment: Did the known_hosts file already existed before? If not make sure it has the correct permissions since it was manually created.

Comment: I got this error:
Warning: Permanently added '54.214.48.139' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).

i used this command:

ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i /path/to/private/key user@host /path/to/script

Comment: This looks to be an issue with your ssh key pair. Try creating new ones. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-ssh-keys--2